# Excel CODE function returning strange result about a non-printable character

Tags: excel

I´m experiencing an odd behavior with excel CODE function. I have a macro (which is working fine) that cleans/replaces weird characters from system data extractions, for the sake of data compatibility on post processing the extracted data in excel. Today I found a new non-printable character in the middle of a string which was fooling VLOOKUP function. So I tried to use CODE function to identify it in the ANSI code table and include it in my macro to replace or delete it. However CODE returned 150 (a regular ndash char), which is wrong. What am I missing?

This is an example with the weird string. It´s is between APPROVER and PME words surrounded with spaces. The second line is the same string with the regular "-" dash character.

Note: I´m using excel 2013 brazilian portuguese version. I translated the formulas for easy comprehension.

| ORIGINAL STRING | RIGHT RESULT | CODE RESULT | SEARCH RESULT on ORIGINAL STRING | SEARCH RESULT on RIGHT STRING |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| APPROVER PME | =RIGHT(A2;5) | =CODE(B2) | =SEARCH(CHAR(150);A2;1) | =SEARCH(CHAR(150);B2;1) |
| APPROVER – PME | =RIGHT(A3;5) | =CODE(B3) | =SEARCH(CHAR(150);A3;1) | =SEARCH(CHAR(150);B3;1) |

These are the results:

| ORIGINAL STRING | RIGHT RESULT | CODE RESULT | SEARCH RESULT on ORIGINAL STRING | SEARCH RESULT on RIGHT STRING |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| APPROVER PME | PME | 150 | #VALUE! | #VALUE! |
| APPROVER – PME | – PME | 150 | 10 | 1 |

The #VALUE! error is "incorrect data type".

Update:
Another weird thing is that when I copy this character from the cell and paste it in Visual Basic code it´s shown as a regular dash character "-".

Comment: Can you use `CLEAN()` and check if the results remain the same? Unfortunately I cannot check since copy-pasting your data won't result in the same.

Comment: @JvdV it removed it, although the function description says it doesn´t: "The CLEAN function was designed to remove the first 32 nonprinting characters in the 7-bit ASCII code (values 0 through 31) from text. In the Unicode character set, there are additional nonprinting characters (values 127, 129, 141, 143, 144, and 157). By itself, the CLEAN function does not remove these additional nonprinting characters. For an example of how to remove these additional nonprinting characters from text, see Top ten ways to clean your data."

Comment: Anyway, I continue to not understand the behavior of the CODE function.

Comment: But it fixed your issue? =)

Comment: I do not understand the formulas and results you posted. Is there an error/typo in your formulas? If I correctly understand your formulas and results, in `B2` you should get `R PME`, not `PME`. Then in `C2` you should get `82` (the code for `R`), not `150`.

Comment: @JvdV not quite. I can use the VBA equivalent clean function (application.worksheetfunction.clean(text)) to remove it. However I won´t have control over which character it's removing. I´ll look deeper into that, My original intent was to find out which character that is in first place.

Comment: @xidgel since I use excel brazilian portuguese, I translated it to its english equivalent but I forgot to replace " ; " by " , " my bad. Actually, `B2` will return the last 5 characters `* PME` (*) being the non-printable character. The original string contains one space after the string `APPROVER` and one space before the string `PME`. So `CODE` on `C2` should return the ANSI number of the non-printable character. Look the row right below it where I replaced it by the atual 150 character `-`.